# C++ include a class in two header files

Tags: c++, header, include, forward

I have to get a project done for university but I can not figure out how it can be done.

The problem is that I want to allocate a Condition object (not a Pointer) in the GameHandler Class like in the example below, but I can not do this because I think of the included Condition.h in the Engine Class. So I am not able to include the Condition class twice. Am I wright?

What can I do to get a solution that works kind like my wrong example?

Thank you a lot!!!

**Condition.h:**

```
#ifndef CONDITION_h
#define CONDITION_h

class Condition
{
  enum Rank {FIRST, SECOND, THIRD};
  void doSomething();
};

#endif
```

**Engine.h**

```
#ifndef ENGINE_h
#define ENGINE_h

#include "Condition.h"

class Engine
{
  Condition::Rank getter();
};

#endif
```

But now I have a third Class which should look like this where I want to create a Condition Object (not a Pointer). How can this be done?

**GameHandler.h**

```
#ifndef GAMEHANDLER_h
#define GAMEHANDLER_h

#include "Condition.h"

class GameHandler
{
  Condition condition_;
  condition_.doSomething();
}

#endif
```

Comment: Did you try compiling it?  Looks OK to me.

Comment: You can't do `condition_.doSomething();` in a class definition like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, class members are private in C++ (more about access specifiers [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)). Try declaring them as public.

```
class Condition
{
public:
  enum Rank {FIRST, SECOND, THIRD};
  void doSomething();
};
```

Also, you cannot call a method within the declaration of a class! You'd have to do it inside a method (for example, the constructor), but the *where* will depend on *what* do you want to do.

```
class GameHandler
{
  Condition condition_;

public:
  GameHandler() {
    condition_.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried now but it has the same problem. 
The problem occurs just when I try to create "Condition condition_" in the GameHandler without trying "condition_.doSomething(). I can not create the Condition object without getting an error from the compiler

Comment: Sorry, check the updated answer, I was missing an error.

Comment: thank you guys for your help! I fixed my problem and it was exactly like @molbdnilo said!

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Using :

```
#ifndef GAMEHANDLER_h
#define GAMEHANDLER_h

/.../

#endif
```

Will prevent multiple inclusion, so it doesn't matter if you include your header multiple times

Comment: Ok but how can I solve my problem because when I do it like in my example I get an error from the compiler:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Condition::Condition()", referenced from:
      GameHandler::GameHandler() in GameHandler.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [basic] Error 1

Comment: You probably forgot to include this header or an other one while using a class defined in them. Check all your file to see if the class they're needing are included.

Comment: @TheoG You declared a default constructor in `Condition` but you never defined it. (The code you posted has other errors, but not that one.)

Comment: @molbdnilo you were wright! I just fixed my program and like you said, i had not declared the default constructor in the Condition class!